# How to transfer a C++ enum into Rust enum?

Tags: c++, rust, ffi

I'm dealing with rust-c++ ffi and I have a C++ enum like this:

```cpp
enum class Code : int {
  Success = 0,
  Failed,

  Full = 10000,
  NotFound,
}
```

I want to use this enum in rust such that any modification on c++ can also be applied in rust.

I have come up an idea:

1. Read the c++ file
2. Parse the enum definition
3. Transfer into a rust enum like this

```rust
pub enum Code {
  Success = 0,
  Failed,

  Full = 10000,
  NotFound,
}
```

But I have to write a intepreter to parse the c++ enum grammar, is there any more convenient way to do so?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what you are asking for correctly, the [bindgen](https://crates.io/crates/bindgen)-crate should be your ticket.
Check out [the documentation](https://docs.rs/bindgen/latest/bindgen/struct.Builder.html#enums) for their `Builder` and how it can generate your Rust code matching the selected enums (in your case).